# [Ruby on Rails]couldn't find file 'jquery-ui/autocomplete' with type 'application/javascript'

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, jquery-ui

I want to use `rails-jquery-autocomplete` gem for my rails application. However I got this error:

```
couldn't find file 'jquery-ui/autocomplete' with type 'application/javascript'
```

My jquery-rails version is 4.3.1 and jquery-ui-rails version is 6.0.1.

application.js

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery-ui/autocomplete
//= require autocomplete-rails
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
//= require moment
//= require bootstrap-datetimepicker
//= require jquery.payment 
//= require credit_card                                                                                                             
//= require map
//= require owl.carousel.min
//= require carousel
//= require react
//= require react_ujs
//= require components
```

application.scss

```
*= require_self                                                                                                                    
*= require jquery-ui
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: It should be `//= require jquery-ui/widgets/autocomplete
` https://github.com/jquery-ui-rails/jquery-ui-rails

Comment: I added this line in my application.js file. However, it can't solve my problem.

Comment: What  error you are getting after adding this?

Comment: I got the the same error message.

Comment: having the same problem here...were you able to solve?

Answer (score 10):

If You have install jquery-ui-rails gem. Remove rails-jquery-autocomplete gem from your project.Just add this line:

```
 //= require jquery-ui/widgets/autocomplete
```

Comment: Also make sure jquery-ui-rails  is in your Gemfile

Answer (score 1):

Restart your server after adding a gem or a library.

Answer (score 0):

I made a temporary fix. My error message complained about `jquery-ui/widgets/autocomplete`.

In my system, the `autocomplete.js` file is at `...gems/jquery-ui-rails-5.0.5/app/assets/javascripts/jquery-ui`. When in that directory, I said

```
mkdir widgets
cd widgets
ln -s ../autocomplete.js autocomplete.js
```

I could not test if autocomplete actually works now, but at least the error message went away.